# Entity-Relationship model: how to model that an employee of a department is working on projects of the same department?

Tags: entity-relationship

I am learning how ER-diagrams are working and I would like to model department/employees/projects/work packages relationships as use-case. Sorry if my questions are too basic, but I really look at a of examples and articles, and could not found any satisfying answer.

My model look like this:

- my company has several departments.
- 1 department manages N employees and 1 employee works for 1 department only - but at least one.
- 1 department controls N projects and 1 project is controlled by one department only - but at least one.
- 1 project consists of N work packages and 1 work package belongs to 1 project only - but at least one project
- 1 employee works on N projects and 1 project can be handled by M employees.
- 1 employee works on N work packages and 1 work packages can be worked on by M employees.

Hopefully it is clear what I mean.

My questions would be:

1. Is there a way in ER-diagram to model the constraint that an employee can only works on projects of the department he belongs? (and not on projects of other departments).
2. Same question: how to model the constraint that an employee can only works on work packages of the project(s) he is working on? (and not on work packages of other projects of other departments)
3. Or may be my questions are not relevant because you cannot model such a behavior using ER-diagrams (and I have to find another way how to represent these behaviors)

I had already a lot of thinking and here it is what finally comes out: (note: the program is used cannot render the arrow for an single but at least one relation, so I use the number "1" instead)

[ER-Model #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SavRL.png)

According to ternary relationship:

- one (employee, project) pair is managed by 1 single department only
- one (department, employee) pair is related to N projects
- one (department, project) pair is related to N employees
- one (employee, work package) pair is related to 1 single project only
- one (project, employee) pair is related to N work packages.
- one (project, work package) pair is related to N employees.

But I am not sure it is enough. So another model I have in mind is:

[ER-Model #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeGpg.png)

This one seems "too much" for me.

Comment: Spontaneous thought. Perhaps with a relationship text between employee - project: "works inside her department on" instead of just "works on"?

Comment: um, not a bad thought. I was expecting something more based on the cardinality of relationships and I suppose this move the problem to a next phase of the DB development - the relational schema for such a relationship. But at least it would be easier to understand. Thanks.

Comment: Using an overview at https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/271264/how-to-represent-foreign-key-in-an-extended-er-model-in-chen-notation and an example at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:ER_Diagram_MMORPG.png, you *might* (absolute guess) need:
`Employee -- M <has> 1 -- Department`,
`Employee -- M <<manages>> N -- [Project] (_ _department_id _ _)`,
`Employee -- M <<works on>> N -- [Project] (_ _department_id_ _)`; 
LEGEND: [ ] = weak entity, << >> = identifying relationship, ( ) = attr., (_ _x_ _) = weak key attr.

Comment: I am not sure to fully understand your comment. I read the link your referenced - and the following links too. My problem has something to do with the limitation of the ER-Cheng model, I think. And that I cannot model on a standard way a foreign key. The idea with the weak entity is interesting. Anyway I don't understand the example you are giving: If I understand right, you have 2 relationships between Employee and Project and none between Project and Department. Moreover the identifying relationships are N-M (I though it should be 1-N). And why is _department_id a weak key attr. of Project?

Comment: The weak entity (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_entity) is for M:N relations where you introduce a "bridge". I do not know enough about identifiying relationships. There simply *are* many Emps and Pros. I made _department_id a weak attribute of the weak entity [Pro] so that an Emp can only work on Pros of the Dpt he belongs to (together with `Emp -- M <has> 1 -- Dpt`). Your #1 proposed `Emp -- M <manages> 1 -- Dpt` + `Emp -- M <manages> 1 -- Pro` + `Emp -- M <works on> 1 -- Pro` might allow other Dpts per Emp / Pro in <works on> since your Dpt constraint is only on <manages>?